# Hazelcast - Loader for Replicated Map

Tags: java, hazelcast

For map we can configure loader to load data from datasource(database). 
loader configure as:

```
  <map name="map-*">
      <map-store enabled="true" initial-mode="LAZY">
         <class-name>com.xyz.loader.CustomMapLoader<class-name>
        </map-store>
  </map>
```

How to load same for replicated map? Or Can we covert map to replicated map?

Answer (score 4):

Replicated Map doesn't support `MapStore`/`MapLoader` and you cannot convert because `IMap` implements `ConcurrentMap` where as `ReplicatedMap` implements `Map`.
Best way is to load the `ReplicatedMap` during initial start of the Hazelcast node or you can do this as a lazy loading as a part of Entry processor for `IMap`.

Hazelcast documentation has multiple warnings for using this map with caution as it is not thread safe and chances of reading stale data is more. Btw, What is your use-case for this feature?

Comment: we need to run distributed task on map where task needs to lookup some small table for that purpose replicated map used for data locality.

Comment: Ok. Makes sense. You can also trigger a task from your client side as executorservice to load that data initially.